# React Typescript - required props issue (typescript marks props as expected from parent while they are to be received from redux)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have small Auth component that is checking for user role number and if the role does have permission the child component is shown.

From the parent component I am passing two values:

- requiredRole which is array of numbers (roles that can access it)
- children (which are components to be shown if the current role matches one of the numbers in the array)

Third value is coming from the state props via connect to the redux:

- auth.role which is a number and is a given role of the current user

My component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '../../reducers';


interface AuthProps {
  requiresRole: number[],
  children: JSX.Element,
  auth: {role: number}
}


export class Auth extends React.Component<AuthProps> {

  render() {

    let { requiresRole } = this.props

    if(!requiresRole.includes(this.props.auth.role)) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <>
        {this.props.children}
      </>
    );
  }
}



export default connect(
  ({ auth }: RootState) => ({ auth }),
  null
)(Auth);
```

Now when I use the component `<Auth requiresRole={[1,2]}>`, it is being flagged by TypeScript with the following error message:

```
Property 'auth' is missing in type '{ children: Element; requiresRole: number[]; }' but required in type 'Omit<ClassAttributes<Auth> & AuthProps, never>'.ts(2741)
```

Sure, I am not passing it as a prop, I am getting it inside the component... .
So how am I to go about this? I could make it optional but it should not be optional as it is required to resolve if user can access the resources or not. Does anyone know how to let TS know I intend to get this information from the redux state and not from the props passed down from the parent?
Thank you for your kind help.